# Jekyll: Accidentally deleted the files in the minima theme folder, when i create a new project and try to open the minima folder, it is empty.

Tags: html, web, jekyll

Jekyll: Accidentally deleted the files in the minima theme folder, when i create a new project and try to open the minima folder, it is empty.

This code i am using

jekyll new website  -- creates new project

cd website,

bundle update minima

bundle show minima

open $(bundle show minima) -- folder is empty (should contain minima files)

And the file that previously (before I deleted the files) contained the _layouts folder and others is now empty.

I have tried uninstalling Jekyll and reinstall, I have also tried updating, creating new projects. Can someone please help!!

Comment: jekyll 3.4.3 | Error:  Could not locate the included file 'icon-github.html' in any of --- this is the code i get now when i try to run the project on the server

Answer (score 0):

You probably deleted the gem files, so make sure it is available to your application with `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably deleted the gem files. To restore the gem to previous state, run:

```bash
$ gem pristine minima
```

If the above doesn't work, uninstalling and re-installing Minima will do the trick:

```bash
$ gem uninstall minima
$ bundle install
```